# How to tell what .swf generated an error?

Tags: flash, runtime-error

I was viewing a page just now and got the error box popup telling me of a runtime error in a .swf The problem is, there are multiple .swfs on the page, and I do not know which one generated the error.

Is there a way to tell?

Comment: perhaps you could try to run each swf in a new window and see if the error appears again?

Comment: That can be difficult if the multiple apps are communicating with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Install the debug version of Flash Player. You can download it from Adobe's website :
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Configure it to save logs as described by Adobe's documentation :
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403009.html

Run the page with it, and look at the log. You can open the textfile directly, or if you use Firefox there is a plugin to display it in a small window beside your page.